# Deleting item on arraylist with checkbox

Tags: java, android, android-studio, checkbox

I am trying to delete an item from an arraylist called arrayofTask
by having checked a checkbox. I have tried many ways to accomplish this, but have been unsuccessful.

Visit https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjSmE.jpg which is where i uploaded a picture of my listview which i add a task and description with an add button.

what i am trying to do is delete such task and description with the click of the checkbox

bellow is what i have been trying to do but i dont know how to proceed.

```
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (checkBox.isChecked()){
                ///i want to delete the arrayoftasks thats located in this location.
                ///tho i am unable to get the location for the tasks in this location.
                ///so if i check the box it should delete the items
            }
        }
    });
```

this is my custom adapter

```
public class userAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<user> {
    public  userAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<user> users){
        super(context,0,users);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        final user User = getItem(position);


        CheckBox checkbox;

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        }

        ///this new
        checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        ///above
        TextView tvTask = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task);
        TextView tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);

        tvTask.setText(User.task);
        tvDescription.setText(User.description);


        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not to open your picture but this code written for recycler view but also work for list view too and when clicking on every checkbox of items, items delete from array list and recycler view.
**pay attention to array list.**

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        //hodler
        holder.txtName.setText(dataObjects.get(position));

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(CheckActivity.context, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    CheckActivity.arrayList.remove(position);
                    CheckActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```